# Integrating Java Look And Feel into Application in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel, synthetica

I'm devloping a java program using netbeans

I added a look and feel to GUI application which is Synthetica AluOxide Look and Feel from this website : http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/themes/ .

I added the Synthetica.jar and syntheticaAluOxide.jar using Add Jar/Folder dialog o my project Libraries.

and then I added this code to my class load :

```
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel;
```

.
.
.

```
try 
    {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but when I run my application I don't get any changes, and I get this error when I click on some component in my application :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
>     at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
>     at
>   sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1003)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1615)  at
>   sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paint(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:498)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.paint(SynthMenuUI.java:283)   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.update(SynthMenuUI.java:248)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:769)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:585)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5212)     at
>   javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5160)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4971)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(FontDesignMetrics.java:217)
>     at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:286)
>     at
>   sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1003)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1615)  at
>   sun.swing.MenuItemLayoutHelper.reset(MenuItemLayoutHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.(SynthMenuItemLayoutHelper.java:119)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paint(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:498)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.paint(SynthMenuItemUI.java:283)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.update(SynthMenuItemUI.java:247)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:769)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1045)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:878)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5212)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
>     at
>   javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:311)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5160)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4971)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: did you try this: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel");`and `((StyleFactory)SynthLookAndFeel.getStyleFactory()).prepareMetalLAFSwitch();`

Comment: everything depends of code ordering, for betterh help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about empty JFrame and main class with a.m. code

Comment: [rest is (as always:-) descibed in FAQ](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/faq/)

Comment: @mKorbel I've already read tha FAQ before I posted this issue

Comment: @fGo None of them has worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Did you include Synthetica's core library 'synthetica.jar'**

1. Ensure that your classpath contains all Synthetica libraries (including
   Synthetica's core library 'synthetica.jar').
2. Enable the Synthetica Look and Feel at startup time in your application:

   ```
   import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaClassyLookAndFeel;


   try {
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaClassyLookAndFeel());
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```